# package cell always destroyed after cluster restart in azure databricks notebook

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I've my shared code in one package cell and I'm using that package to some other notebook cell. But everytime cluster restart, that package cell get destroyed and my notebook where I'm using that package doesn't find it and throws error like `error: object abc is not a member of package com import com.abc.utility.Shared`.

Code for package cell in separate notebook is like

```
package com.abc.utility
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

object Shared {
def outputFilesOperation(dbfsMountPoint : String) {
//stuff here
}
```

Separate Notebook, where I'm using above package

```
import com.abc.utility.Shared
Shared.outputFilesOperation(dbfsMountPoint = "/mnt/abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the first notebook into notebook where you're using the object - you can do it via `%run`, in a separate cell: `%run ./FirstNotebookName` (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html))

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott actually I already plan on that approach...
Ohh... I thought package cell compile automatically when cluster starts.

Comment: No. if they in the notebook, then they should be executed some way